# Mysterious pause in Spring + Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, hikaricp

I'm trying to import data into an Oracle database using Spring and Hibernate. I'm baffled by a mysterious pause which is crippling the performance of my program.

Here's a typical cycle. Note the gap of a minute and a half after "disabling autocommit".

```
2014-10-23 12:03:20,054 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtaining JDBC connection
2014-10-23 12:03:20,054 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtained JDBC connection
2014-10-23 12:03:20,054 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] DEBUG o.h.e.t.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - begin
2014-10-23 12:03:20,054 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - initial autocommit status: true
2014-10-23 12:03:20,054 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - disabling autocommit
2014-10-23 12:04:52,759 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] DEBUG o.h.e.t.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - committing
2014-10-23 12:04:52,759 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
2014-10-23 12:04:52,759 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Dirty checking collections
2014-10-23 12:04:52,760 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 100 objects
2014-10-23 12:04:52,760 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
2014-10-23 12:04:52,760 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] DEBUG o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter - Listing entities:
```

(ton of logged entity data snipped)

```
2014-10-23 12:04:52,761 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] DEBUG o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter - More......
2014-10-23 12:04:52,831 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - committed JDBC Connection
2014-10-23 12:04:52,831 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - re-enabling autocommit
2014-10-23 12:04:52,831 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Releasing JDBC connection
2014-10-23 12:04:52,831 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Released JDBC connection
```

Java code that writes to the database (BATCH_SIZE == 100 for the log above):

```
OracleDao odao = (OracleDao) mainCtx.getBean("oracleDao");
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, (rows.size() - 1) / BATCH_SIZE)
  .mapToObj(i -> {
    int end = (i + 1) * BATCH_SIZE;
    if (end > rows.size()) {
       end = rows.size();
    }
    return rows.subList(i * BATCH_SIZE, end);
  })
  .parallel()
  .forEach(batch -> {
    odao.saveBatch(batch);
  });
```

OracleDao.saveBatch() is pretty simple:

```
@Transactional
public void saveBatch (List<?> rows) {
  Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

  rows.stream().forEach(row -> session.saveOrUpdate(row));

  return;
}
```

EDIT: Here's my application context (for some reason including it in the original post made Stack Overflow think it was spam):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.mydomain" />

  <bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="url">(url)</prop>
        <prop key="user">(user)</prop>
        <prop key="password">(password)</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="oracleDS" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleDS" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
      <list>
        <value>com.mydomain.dao</value>
        <value>com.mydomain.data</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
          <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="false" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
    <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="oracleEMF" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleDS" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
      <list>
        <value>com.mydomain.dao</value>
        <value>com.mydomain.data</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="oracleDao" class="com.mydomain.dao.OracleDao" />

  <tx:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

Versions:

- Hibernate 4.3.6
- Spring 4.1.0
- HikariCP 2.1.0
- Java 8u25

I don't think it's waiting on other threads because taking out the parallel() doesn't have any effect on the length of the pause.

Setting the Hibernate batch size rather than using manual batching resulted in no mention of batching at all in the log.

What am I missing?

**ETA 2:** Here's a typical stack if I pause it:

```
SocketInputStream.socketRead0(FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) line: not available [native method]    
SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int, int) line: 150 
SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) line: 121  
DataPacket(Packet).receive() line: 308  
DataPacket.receive() line: 106  
NetInputStream.getNextPacket() line: 324    
NetInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) line: 268 
NetInputStream.read(byte[]) line: 190   
NetInputStream.read() line: 107 
T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket() line: 124  
T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read() line: 80 
T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1() line: 1137  
T4C8Oall(T4CTTIfun).receive() line: 350 
T4C8Oall(T4CTTIfun).doRPC() line: 227   
T4C8Oall.doOALL(boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean, OracleStatement$SqlKind, int, byte[], int, Accessor[], int, Accessor[], int, byte[], char[], short[], int, DBConversion, byte[], InputStream[][], byte[][][], OracleTypeADT[][], OracleStatement, byte[], char[], short[], T4CTTIoac[], int[], int[], int[], NTFDCNRegistration) line: 531 
T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean) line: 208 
T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe() line: 886 
T4CPreparedStatement(OracleStatement).executeMaybeDescribe() line: 1175 
T4CPreparedStatement(OracleStatement).doExecuteWithTimeout() line: 1296 
T4CPreparedStatement(OraclePreparedStatement).executeInternal() line: 3613  
T4CPreparedStatement(OraclePreparedStatement).executeQuery() line: 3657 
OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery() line: 1495    
PreparedStatementJavassistProxy(PreparedStatementProxy).executeQuery() line: 44 
ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(PreparedStatement) line: 82 
SingleTableEntityPersister(AbstractEntityPersister).getDatabaseSnapshot(Serializable, SessionImplementor) line: 1533    
StatefulPersistenceContext.getDatabaseSnapshot(Serializable, EntityPersister) line: 316 
ForeignKeys.isTransient(String, Object, Boolean, SessionImplementor) line: 255  
DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener(AbstractSaveEventListener).getEntityState(Object, String, EntityEntry, SessionImplementor) line: 511   
DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent) line: 100   
DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent) line: 90 
SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent) line: 684   
SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(String, Object) line: 676  
SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(Object) line: 671  
OracleDao.lambda$0(Session, ?) line: 32 
1717941961.accept(Object) line: not available   
ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator<E>.forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E>) line: 1374  
ReferencePipeline$Head<E_IN,E_OUT>.forEach(Consumer<? super E_OUT>) line: 580   
OracleDao.saveBatch(List<?>) line: 32   
OracleDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9cbb7611.invoke(int, Object, Object[]) line: not available   
MethodProxy.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 204  
CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint() line: 717 
CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation(ReflectiveMethodInvocation).proceed() line: 157 
TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation() line: 98   
TransactionInterceptor(TransactionAspectSupport).invokeWithinTransaction(Method, Class<?>, InvocationCallback) line: 266    
TransactionInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 95    
CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation(ReflectiveMethodInvocation).proceed() line: 179 
CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Object, Method, Object[], MethodProxy) line: 653  
OracleDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f5d535ab.saveBatch(List) line: not available  
Importer.lambda$9(OracleDao, List<MdbData>) line: 77    
626211770.accept(Object) line: not available    
ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef<T>.accept(T) line: 183   
IntPipeline$4$1.accept(int) line: 250   
Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(IntConsumer) line: 110 
Streams$RangeIntSpliterator(Spliterator$OfInt).forEachRemaining(Consumer<Integer>) line: 693    
IntPipeline$4(AbstractPipeline<E_IN,E_OUT,S>).copyInto(Sink<P_IN>, Spliterator<P_IN>) line: 512 
ForEachOps$ForEachTask<S,T>.compute() line: 290 
ForEachOps$ForEachTask<S,T>(CountedCompleter<T>).exec() line: 731   
ForEachOps$ForEachTask<S,T>(ForkJoinTask<V>).doExec() line: 289 
ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinTask<?>) line: 902   
ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue, int) line: 1689   
ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue) line: 1644   
ForkJoinWorkerThread.run() line: 157
```

Aha, you say, it's waiting to read so it must be a network problem. But doing this import from a text file with sqlldr (part of a painful manual process that I'm trying to replace), running on the same host, accessing the same database, runs orders of magnitude faster. So I don't think it's a problem with the speed of the connection.

Comment: I'm not completely sure but when I confronted some batch insert/update case, I used native queries and plain JDBC instead relying on hibernate capabilities and worked great. Not sure if you can adapt this to your specific case.

Comment: If you get a thread dump at the time of the pause, is there anything interesting to see or is it truly waiting in the setAutoCommit() call of the Connection?  The other thing is, if you are truly using a transaction manager, try setting auto-commit to ``false`` by default in the connection pool.

Comment: Why do you have both a `SessionFactory` and `EntityManagerFactory` to the same datasource? Remove the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` and replace that with `HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean` which exposes the `SessionFactory` used by the `EntityManagerFactory` this also allows you to replace the `HibernateTransactionManager`  with the `JpaTransactionManager`. Is the only `@Transactional` on your `saveBatch` method or is that inside another `@Transactional` method? Why are you doing a lookup for the `OracleDao` you should inject it. You aren't constructing another `ApplicationContext` yourself are you?

Comment: M. Deinum: Two things relying on the same data source because I'm new to Spring and the reference I'm working from isn't clear about that. Do you think the adjustment you suggest is likely to clear up this problem?

saveBatch() is the only thing with a @Transactional tag.